# Cannot execute SQLite query on a file

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

I have a weird problem where I cannot execute the simplest query on an SQLite database file while the code works on another file. There is no error when creating a new PDO instance. The permission is sufficient for read-only purposes (644).

```
try 
{
  $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$db");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
  echo "Database not loaded successfully. ";
  die();
}
```

But when I run:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('select * from message');
$result = $sth->execute();
```

or

```
$result = $dbh->query('select * from message');
```

both return `FALSE`.

It throws error: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 14 unable to open database file'" on `$dbh->prepare` line.

Again, the above code runs okay on another database file.

Another info: I *can* open the problematic file just fine in MesaSQLite (a SQLite file viewer on Mac).

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this. Don't know if it will help

```
<?php

try {
    // create a new instance of a PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=myDatabase", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql='SELECT * FROM message';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo "<pre>";var_dump($row);echo"</pre>";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // if the connection fails, display an error message
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $errmsg = $e->getMessage();
    error_log('$errmsg-> '.$errmsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reason they return false, when that happens you have to check the errors, and go fix them:

- Check error when connecting.
- Check error when preparing.
- Check error when executing

**Using `prepare()`:**

```
try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$db");
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('select * from message');

    if(!$sth) {
        echo "prepare failed() :\n";
        print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
        die();
    }

    $success = $sth->execute();

    if(!$success) {
        echo "execute failed() :\n";
        print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
        die();
    }

    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    var_dump($result);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo "PDO Exception caught: ";
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
```

**Using `query()`:**

```
try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$db");
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $sth = $dbh->query('select * from message');

    if(!$sth) {
        echo "query() failed :\n";
        print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
        die();
    }

    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

    if($result) {
        var_dump($result);
    }else{
        echo "No result !";
    }


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo "PDO Exception caught: ";
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
```

To set error mode while creating connection:

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$db", null, null,
               array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

Comment: It appears that it cannot open database file on `$dbh->prepare` line. It's weird that it doesn't catch the problem when connecting to the database file. The above code works on a different database file.

Comment: @user173457 it's because the error attribute is set after connection try this approach `$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$db", null, null,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));` and you will see the errors!